# Execute Oracle Function to export data to Excel file "Using Generating excel documents on-the-fly from PHP5"

Tags: php, excel, oracle, codeigniter

```
function EXCEL_PER_GET(
TABLE_ID_in number,
TABLE_N_IN NUMBER,
NAME_TYPE_in number)     return varchar2

  as

    CURSOR CUR IS
    select *
    from   PER_DATA_Vw
    where  TABLE_ID=  TABLE_ID_in and  TABLE_N=TABLE_N_IN and
            NAME_TYPE = NAME_TYPE_in
    order by NAME_TYPE;

    data_V varchar2(22000);
    dt_fm_v varchar2(2000);
    cnt number:=0;

begin
    data_V:=',,,,,,';
    FOR REC IN CUR LOOP 
..... ... 
END LOOP;
```

In PHP file:

```
 public function ToExcel(){
          // load library
        require __DIR__ . "/../helpers/php-excel.php";
      ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
      $filename='Report-'.date('d-m-Y');
      $res = $this->total_res_model->get_ma(NULL,'*',NULL,"D_ALL_RSFNTAL_MA_AND_DET");
       $xls = new Excel_XML('UTF-8', false, 'My Test Sheet');
      $data = array();

      array_push($data,array(


      ));
      array_push($data,array(
         0=>"ID_MID_DETTER"));

      foreach($res as $need){

          $row[1] =  $need->BLD_STATUS_NAME;
        //THIS IS A PROBLEM FOR NOW HOW PHP execute THE FUNCTION AND GET IT          USING FORLOOP. 
          //  EXCEL_PKG.EXCEL_PERSONS_GET
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How i can using a php code to execute the stored procedure ...EXCEL_PKG.EXCEL_PERSONS_GET and wana to put it in array to export it in a csv excel file ... the important part how to execute the function and send it with array ...iam using helper like i say to export this file.

Comment: You should be able to run sql like `select EXCEL_PKG.EXCEL_PERSONS_GET(your, params, gohere) as res from dual` and the resulting recordset will have one record with fieldname `res`

Comment: Sorry i don't understand (your, params, gohere)... Can i have example...

Comment: How to define a procedure to call a function in oracle? sorry i don't Have alot idea of Oracle

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html

Comment: really Thank you Mrs.Tim Willisms i will read it now